# "Playback" a list of images in swing

Tags: java

In my application a user can record 2 seconds of frames (at 30 fps). I'm recording a depth histogram using an xbox kinect.

The 2 seconds of recording result in an array of 60 BufferedImage instances.

I want to implement a 'playback' option which will open up a new JFrame in which the 60 images will be displayed at 30 images per second.

I'm a bit confused on how to approach this feature. I need to repaint the component every 33ms to achieve 30fps, but how do I stall the repaint without blocking the user interface? This is what I've tested so far:

```
package view;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

/**
 * Created by X on 15/08/16.
 */
public class PlaybackView extends Component {
    private BufferedImage[] images;
    private int counter = 0;

    public PlaybackView(BufferedImage[] images){
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(images[counter], 0,0, this);
    }

    public void run(){
        while (counter < 60){
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(33);
            }catch (InterruptedException e){}
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Instance is created in this piece of code:

```
btnPlayback.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TreePath[] paths = treeRecordings.getSelectionPaths();
            for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++){
                if (mapper.get((DefaultMutableTreeNode) paths[i].getLastPathComponent()) != null){
                    Recording recording = mapper.get((DefaultMutableTreeNode)paths[i].getLastPathComponent());
                    JFrame quickframe = new JFrame("Playback " + recording.getEntry().getName() + " - " + recording.getNumber());
                    PlaybackView player = new PlaybackView(recording.getPlayback());
                    quickframe.add(player);
                    quickframe.setVisible(true);
                    player.run();
                    quickframe.dispose();
                    return;
                }
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No valid selection of recordings", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    });
```

The created Frame starts in minimum size (can't see anything) and can't be opened (I think because Thread.sleep() is called on ui thread). What would be the best way to solve my issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the issue myself so I'll leave my solution here in case it could help others.

Worked with a Timer instance (swing) that gets triggered every 33ms.

My class now looks like this:

```
package view;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

/**
 * Created by xyz on 15/08/16.
 */
public class PlaybackView extends Component {
    private BufferedImage[] images;
    private Timer timer;
    private int counter = 0;


    public PlaybackView(BufferedImage[] images){
        this.images = images;
        timer = new Timer(33, new TimerListener());
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(images[counter], 0,0, this);
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
            counter = (counter + 1) % 60;
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers